# Fail to get data from ssl site

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7

Alright, so I have this server running with a wildcard cert at https://www.octgn.net .
In every browser I try everything works fine, except I am having users who have issues connecting.

The main concern here is that I have api calls in my software that goes over ssl and for some users it just never works. This is the exception I gathered

```
WARN  2013-05-07 16:18:12,562 3.1.18.102 [11] Octgn.Launcher.LoginNew [(null)] - Login Request Failed
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOException: The decryption operation failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The message received was unexpected or badly formatted
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessReadErrorCode(SecurityStatus errorCode, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Byte[] extraBuffer)
at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessFrameBody(Int32 readBytes, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameBody(Int32 readBytes, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartReading(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.TlsStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
at Octgn.Launcher.LoginNew.<>c__DisplayClass14.<DoLogin>b__13() in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\OCTGN-Release\octgnFX\Octgn\Launcher\LoginNew.xaml.cs:line 269
```

My code looks like this

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    try
    {
        Log.Info("Sending login request");
        var ustring = AppConfig.WebsitePath + "api/user/login.php?username=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(username)
                      + "&password=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(password);
        if (email != null) ustring += "&email=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(email);
        var res = wc.DownloadString(new Uri(ustring));
        res = res.Trim();
        Log.Info("Do Login Request Result: " + res);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.Warn("Login Request Failed",e);
        this.LoginFinished(LoginResult.Failure, DateTime.Now,"Please try again later.");
    }
}
```

Any idea's? I'm not sure if it's my fault, maybe I need to put my public key in the software and somehow inject that into my calls, or maybe the users computer is setup funny or something?

Every indication I can get is that my ssl is correct, and I don't get this from a lot of users, but it happens every time for a few, and I'm not sure what's wrong here.

More info:
quote from the user

> "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage."
>
> Works fine on every other browser though."

Also, another quote

> Here's a screenshot of my SSL test results: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=l9wtu&s=5
>
> I've tried adding https://*.octgn.net to IE. Doesn't seem to make a difference.
>
> If it helps, it says on the login page that I cant retrieve the news headlines either.

The news headline is an xml document on the server as well

Also the app that calls the server is a client side application, it's not a browser app.

Comment: checked if there are special chars/escape sequences in username/password/email that may cause encoding issues ?

Comment: I didn't think to check that, but also take a look at my recent addition to the post.

Comment: Yeah, the data passed is only letters and numbers

Answer (score 0):

cross domain requests over ssl may have issues. check this link.

http://www.voiceoftech.com/swhitley/index.php/2006/07/ssl-crossing-domains-and-flex/

Comment: It's not cross domain, this is a wpf app.